# How can i enable execute perms for my entire HDD?

Tags: debian, permissions, hard-disk, steam

All of my games are stored on a secondary drive in my pc and steam says i need execute permission. i have run the command `"sudo chmod -R +x /mountpoints/HDD"` and other similar ones yet none of them work, can anyone tell me why?

(I'm running Plasma KDE on Debian 11 if it helps)

```
$ df -h /mountpoints/HDD
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda1       1.8T  339G  1.4T  20% /mountpoints/HDD
```

I mount the drive using "KDE Partition Manager", there is a screenshot below of what i did. then i just right-click mounted it in dolphin
[image]

Other relevant command output:

```
$ ls -ld /mountpoints/HDD
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  5 15:29 /mountpoints/HDD

$ sudo grep /dev/sda1 /etc/fstab
/dev/sda1                                   /mountpoints/HDD   ext4   sync,users          0 0
```

Comment: its a ext4 system. should i still run that?

Comment: the output is this
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       1.8T  339G  1.4T  20% /mountpoints/HDD`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us how you mount the drive. Also please show us the output of `sudo grep /dev/sda1 /etc/fstab`. Finally, NEVER run things like `sudo chmod -R +x /mountpoints/HDD`, that would set everything as executable and could break things such as ssh keys and other permission-sensitive issues.

Comment: ok, i have edited the question with more information (sorry im new to all of this, did i do it right?)

Comment: That's fine, I just tweaked the formatting a little. However, it looks like you missed some of the `sudo grep /dev/sda1 /etc/fstab` output, could you please check again and make sure you post the entire thing?

Comment: yes sorry, the full output is `/dev/sda1                                   /mountpoints/HDD   ext4   sync,users          0 0`

Comment: `sync` is almost certainly a really bad idea for a HDD that is used to store game data, unless saving data goes much too fast for your taste; but it's not the source of your problems.

Comment: ok, do you have any sources that can tell me how to change it from sync @MarcusMüller ? (if i can)

Comment: delete `,sync` from your line. that's it.

Comment: where can i do that? ive only been using linux for 2 weeks @MarcusMüller

Comment: you're giving us the content of a file. That file.